# A trigonometry problem for a graphic designer (includes graphic)

Tags: trigonometry

I am in no way a mathematician, I am a graphic designer by trade but I do like precision in what I do.

Quite a tricky one to describe hence the attached graphic, however, in words;

> I have punched a circle out of a square of the same dimensions. I have discarded all but the top left corner shape. I'd now like to *round* this corner off. So at 30 degrees from the top right I have created a point, from this point I'd like to draw a circle (green) until it fills the available space.
>
> I therefore want to calculate the radius of the green circle. But my limited maths knowledge means I'm struggling and would be very grateful for any help.
>
> I have the angles a, b and c. I also have the lengths of d, e and f.

[image: rounded-corner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If radius of green circle is $r$, then for length $OD$:
$$
OD = OB+BC+CD,\\
\frac d{\cos a} = d + r + \frac r{\cos a},\\
r\left(\frac 1{\cos a}+1\right) = d\left(\frac 1{\cos a}-1\right)
r = d\frac{1-\cos a}{1+\cos a}
$$

If $a=30°$, then $r = (7-4\sqrt 3)d \approx 0.0718\ d$.

[image]

Comment: This is mind blowing, I quickly finished off the design work after sizing the _green_ circle correctly, and I'm now returning to try and get my head round the equation. I'm incredibly grateful for the help, thank you @vasily-mitch

Comment: Glad to help. You might refresh basic trigonometry in a right triangle and notice the similarity between small red triangle and big $OAD$